# How to centre Image in Xamarin.Forms without stretching it

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got this `ContentPage`:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Image
            Source="background.png"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
        />
        <Image
            Source="logo.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
        />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

But logo.png (while vertically and horizontally entered), stretches to take up the entire width of the screen.

How do I stop it from stretching and just maintaining its original size?
And yes, XAML solution definitely preferred.

**Edit 1** (based on Paul Kertscher's answer):

If I set the Image source to a URL (e.g. https://via.placeholder.com/450x300.png?text=Computer+Says+No), I get the expected result, i.e the image does not stretch. However, if I save this same image to the specific platform directory (say Resources/ComputerSaysNo.png for iOS), it stretches to take up the entire screen width.
Tested on iPhone 7 simulator.

**Edit 2**
If I make @2x and @3x copies of my logo.png in the iOS Resources directory, and have all three images the same size, it works differently; the logo does not stretch to take up the entire width of the page.

Comment: Did you try `Aspect = "AspectFill"`

Comment: It does not work. I would've thought AspectFill would fill up the view with the image. And this is what it seems to do. See my Edit 1.

Comment: You are confusing, sometimes working, sometimes not. What screenshot you have added "It does not work" is this called image?. Show clear screenshot with image so that people can help you & do not use media sites like  https://via.placeholder.com, few of developer might not have access to those.

Comment: What is your original size of your logo picture?I put a picture with my own and use your code, it works fine.

Comment: @jackHua The logo is roughly 400px wide and 150px high. Is your logo image in the iOS Resources directory?

Comment: @Arvindraja Edited my question, should be clearer now. I have to use a URL as an example to demonstrate using a URL source for an image.

Comment: @jackHua Please have a look at my Edit 2.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.aspect?view=xamarin-forms) about `AspectFill`

> Scale the image to fill the view. Some parts may be clipped in order to fill the view.

You should use `AspectFit` instead, it does not stretch the image to fill the control, but to fit the whole image in the control:

> Scale the image to fit the view. Some parts may be left empty (letter boxing).

**EDIT**

I've tried the following

```
<Grid>
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           Source="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-200-200-6.jpg" />
</Grid>
```

and it yielded the following layout:

[image: Screenshot of the resulting app. There is an image displayed in the middle without stretching.]

Hence it looks like what I've proposed is right - at least principally. I'd guess your image is simply too large.

Anyway, if you want to keep that image or would like to have more control over how the image is displayed, you could opt to either one of the following options.

Use the grid system to determine the size of the image

Within the `Grid` you can define columns and rows. Columns (and rows respectively) defined with the width (height) of `*` will take all the available space. If there are multiple columns or rows with `*` size, they will devide the remaining space equally. Furthermore you can give the `*` columns and rows weights. Ar column with the width `2*` will have twice the width of one with the width `*`. Hence you could define columns with width `3*`, `*`, and `3*` and place your image in the second column (column index `1`) for the image to take `1/7th` of the screen width.

Use an `AbsoluteLayout`

Within an `AbsoluteLayout` you can define positions and sizes of child elements. Instead of positioning the images in a `Grid`, you could do the following

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" /> <!-- Background -->
    <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,.2,.2" /> <!-- Logo with 20% width/height  -->
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

If you preferred setting the size of the image absolutely, you can do the following

```
<Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,150,150" />
```

Comment: My original xaml used AspectFit. Same problem.

Comment: @AjLearning A screenshot of what it looks like (and maybe a sketch how you wnat it to look) would really be helpful.

Comment: What I want is something like the default Xamarin splash screen. In my case the logo would be the X shape. But what’s happening is my logo is stretched to takeup the whole width of the screen. So imagine the X stretched out until the hexagon’s sides touch the sides of the screen.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Actually I think if the image is really smaller than the screen the while `Image` view should not be expanded to fill the whole thing. Just gimme a moment and I'll try something

Comment: Thanks Paul. I know how row and column definitions work though. I did make an interesting discovery though. Please see Edit 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which I use quite often is AbsoluteLayout. Combining PositionProportional (LayoutFlags) with LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1 (X, Y, Width, Height) will put image in the center of the screen. The LayoutBounds "0.5" means it will be in the center of X and Y, and "-1" will help to ignore the width and height.
Make sure to set VerticalOptions to in your AbsoluteLayout.

Here is the code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
        <Image Source="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-200-200-6.jpg" />
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I hope it helps.